# Why does decltype remove const from return types for built-in types?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

As a general rule, `decltype` preserves constness:

```
const int ci = 0;
decltype(ci)  x;         // x is const int
x = 5;                   // error--x is const

class Gadget{}:

const Gadget makeCG();         // factory

decltype(makeCG()) y1, y2;     // y1 and y2 are const Gadgets
y1 = y2;                       // error--y1 is const
```

But for `const` return types that return fundamental types, `decltype` seems to throw `const` away:

```
const int makeCI();            // factory

decltype(makeCI()) z;          // z is NOT const
z = 5;                         // okay
```

Why does `decltype` discard constness in this case?  I mean the question in two ways:

1. What part of the standard specifies this behavior?
2. What is the motivation for specifying the behavior this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to return by const value?

Comment: @BillyONeal: A good question, but that doesn't invalidate this one.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I never claimed that it did.

Comment: @BillyONeal: My interest is in understanding decltype, and because it treats return-by-value differently for user-defined and fundamental types, I'd simply like to know why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The behavior you observe is correct:  `decltype(makeCI())` is `int`, not `int const`.

The `makeCI()` function call expression is a prvalue expression.  Per C++11 §3.10[basic.lval]/4:

> Class prvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types.

The term "cv-qualification" refers to const- and volatile-qualification.  `int` is not a class type, so the type of the rvalue expression `makeCI()` is `int` and it is not const-qualified.

(In recent drafts of the C++ language standard, e.g. N3690, this text has been removed and replaced by new text at §5[expr]/6, which states, "If a prvalue initially has the type "cv T," where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis."  See [CWG defect 1261](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1261) for details.)

Comment: I really need to pay more attention I think. +1.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the part of the standard that addresses this question. Any insight into the motivation?

Comment: I do not know the history of this rule.  This rule is present in C++98.  In most cases, it doesn't matter.  (E.g., most of the built-in operations require a modifiable lvalue where modification occurs, so const-qualification of rvalue expressions doesn't matter.)