# Deducing constness of type returned by function

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, return-value

Is there a way to tell whether a function returns a const or a non-const value? `decltype` works for references, but it won't work for non-reference types.

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename >
struct print_type;      //undefined

int main(){
  auto lambda = []()->const int{ return 0; };
  print_type< decltype(lambda()) > dt;   //print_type< int >
  print_type< typename std::result_of<decltype(lambda)()>::type > ro;  
    //print_type< int >


  return 0;
}
```

I implemented a `std::tuple` transform function, that will call a function object on each tuple element and store the result in a new `tuple` composed of return types. This doesn't work for const return types, which is pretty surprising (but needed).

Comment: `decltype` will not maintain the `const`-ness of a return value (as you've noticed). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502188/why-does-decltype-remove-const-from-return-types-for-built-in-types

Comment: For non-class, non-array types, no, there isn't a way (that I know of, I can always hold out hope). For class-types its trivial. In your example `int` is obviously neither a class-type nor array-type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct has_operator
{    
    template <typename U>
    struct SFINAE {};

    template <typename U>
    static std::true_type test(SFINAE<decltype(&U::operator())>*);

    template <typename U>
    static std::false_type test(...);

    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value;
};

template <bool value, typename T>
struct check_constness;

template <typename T>
struct check_constness<false, T>
{        
    template <typename R, typename... Args>
    static std::true_type const_or_not(const R(*)(Args...));

    static std::false_type const_or_not(...);

    using type = decltype(const_or_not(std::declval<T*>()));
};

template <typename T>
struct check_constness<true, T>
{        
    template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
    static std::true_type const_or_not(const R(C::*)(Args...));

    template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
    static std::true_type const_or_not(const R(C::*)(Args...) const);

    template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
    static std::true_type const_or_not(const R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile);

    template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
    static std::true_type const_or_not(const R(C::*)(Args...) volatile);

    static std::false_type const_or_not(...);

    using type = decltype(const_or_not(&T::operator()));
};

template <typename T>
using is_const_ret_type = typename check_constness<has_operator<T>::value, T>::type;

int glob() { return 0; }
const int cglob() { return 0; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    int x = 123;

    auto lambda = []() -> int { return 0; };

    auto clambda = []() -> const int { return 0; };

    auto closure = [x]() -> int { return x; };

    auto cclosure = [x]() -> const int { return x; };

    std::cout << is_const_ret_type<decltype(lambda)>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_const_ret_type<decltype(clambda)>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_const_ret_type<decltype(glob)>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_const_ret_type<decltype(cglob)>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_const_ret_type<decltype(closure)>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_const_ret_type<decltype(cclosure)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
false
true
false
true
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89b892a9a817094f)

Comment: Nice. Can you explain, or point to some place that explains, how `C` is deduced given a lambda function?

Comment: It seems to me that this trick wouldn't work for a closure as it is not implicitly convertible to a function pointer. Very nice and useful though.

Comment: And... since we're taking an address of a member function, this won't work for overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: @tsuki: how about now?

Comment: Did you avoid the "works in C++11 but not in C++14 because of `auto` lambda"s problem?  Not at first glance.  I'd be tempted to use `decltype` or `result_of` to get the nominal return type, then pass in both the `args...` and nominal return type and extract the `const` status of the return type, rather than asking the unanswerable in general question in the presence of `template` `operator()`s?

Comment: `[](auto&&...)->const int{return 7;}` -- you cannot take an address of `operator()` and expect it to work, not without providing the `Args...` and possibly `R`.  For a more fundamental version, `[](auto&&...args)->std::conditional_t<sizeof...(args)==1, int, const double> { return 7; }`, where the return type of `operator()` varies depending on what `args...` are passed to it.  Basically, pointers to `operator()` need a context -- as there can be more than one, and in C++14 this will be common even with lambdas.

Comment: @Yakk: you still can take address using `&T::template operator()<Args...>`. And yes, above solution won't work with `auto` params as of now as I can't deduce whether it is `(auto...)` or `(auto a, auto b)`.

Comment: @Yakk: and I am aware this doesn't work with overloaded functions as well, because it depends on pointers rather than calling convention. I wish you posted your solution if you have one.

Comment: If you pass `R(Args...)` into your traits class, you can cast `T::operator()` into `R(T::*)(Args...)` and `R const(T::*)(Args...)`.  Sadly I don't know of a way to go from `Args...` I want to invoke an operator with, to pointer-to-method, or ditto for a function.  Hmm.  Does `decltype(auto)` deduction avoid stripping the `const` off?

Comment: Ie, `template<class F>struct helper{ F f; decltype(auto) operator()(auto&&...args){return t(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }`, then take a pointer-to `helper<F>::operator()` and pass it to overloaded functions taking `R(helper<F>::*)(Args&&...)` and `R const(helper<F>::*)(Args&&...)` overloads and see which one bites?  I'm trying to ponder here, I don't got a solution.  Need to check `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @Yakk: [some variation about that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffac8ac857755667)

Comment: `std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value` could be shortened to `decltype(test<T>(nullptr))::value`. Or, as someone (T.C.?) suggested, you could define a `using type = decltype(test<T>(nullptr));` member type.

Answer (score 5):

For non built-in types, you can use `std::is_const` and `decltype` to get what you want.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   {
      auto lambda = []()->A{ return A(); };
      std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(lambda())>::value << std::endl;
   }

   {
      auto lambda = []()->const A{ return A(); };
      std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(lambda())>::value << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::result_of to get the return type of a callable object.

Remember that returning a const int is impossible, the compiler will ignore the qualification. GCC has a warning for this. Something in -Wall -Wextra -pedantic turns that on.